# how to cache count function in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, caching, count, laravel-5.1

I want to cache the count function of my *acqusition* model.

Indeed I have 1 800 000 acquis, and i dont want to count this every time.

I don't want to do it in each controllers I use like :

```
$count = ( ! Cache::has('count_acquisition')) ? Cache::put('count_acquisition', Acquisition::count(), 60) : Cache::get('count_acquisition');
```

It's quite heavy, I would prefer to do this directly in my Acquisition model, but I don't how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static `count`method in your `Acquisition` model:

```php
public static function count()
{
    return Cache::remember('count_acquisition', 60, function () {
        return static::query()->count();
    });
}
```

Then in your controllers, simply call this method:

```php
$count = Acquisition::count();
```

Comment: Ok I can use return static::count();

Comment: overriding public static function count() also ok  ?

Comment: Ok I found "Retrieve Or Update" laravel method that you used ! Thank Joseph.